# C++: std::istream check for EOF without reading / consuming tokens / using operator>>

Tags: c++, filestream, iostream, eof

I would like to test if a `std::istream` has reached the end without reading from it.

I know that I can check for EOF like this:

```
if (is >> something)
```

but this has a series of problems. Imagine there are many, possibly virtual, methods/functions which expect `std::istream&` passed as an argument.
This would mean I have to do the "housework" of checking for EOF in each of them, possibly with different type of `something` variable, or create some weird wrapper which would handle the scenario of calling the input methods.

All I need to do is:

```
if (!IsEof(is)) Input(is);
```

the method `IsEof` should guarantee that the stream is not changed for reading, so that the above line is equivalent to:

```
Input(is)
```

as regards the data read in the `Input` method.

If there is no generic solution which would word for and `std::istream`, is there any way to do this for `std::ifstream` or `cin`?

**EDIT:**
In other words, the following `assert` should always pass:

```
while (!IsEof(is)) {
  int something;
  assert(is >> something);
}
```

Comment: Re-reading the question, I'm not sure I understood the first time. Do you really mean `if (IsEof(is)) Input(is)` or should there be a logical NOT in there?

Comment: It should be logical not. But what is important is I need a check without consuming any tokens first (see the EDIT above) and everything will be clear to you.

Comment: Post-edit that assert is very strong. It states the `IsEof` should return false only if a formatted extraction of an `int` will succeed. Are you sure this is what you mean? If so you can't do this with raw `istream`; you would need some sort of structured cache so that you could read and cache the next int. Alternatively you would need a way to put back all the characters read in the parsing of an `int` and `std::istream` doesn't guarantee that this will always be possible.

Comment: This `int` is just an example, I would like this to work regardless of what is the next token, whenever the EOF is reached. Yes, I am looking for a function which would tell me if I reached the position after the last token in the stream (i.e. EOF), without trying to read the next token, or at least to read it in advance and put it back. Is this possible?

Comment: Just for clarification, what exactly do you mean by 'token'? If your talking about arbitrarily complex types then - presumably - the next 'token' could consist of arbitratily many characters and you're going to have to attempt a fake read of the entire object. If this read fails you're going to have to store everything that's been read in a cache (maybe structured, maybe not) because you are not going to be able - in general - to push it all back onto a simple `istream`.

Comment: @leden: what you describe is a scanner or tokenizer. Build one yourself or generate one using a generator (Coco/R, flex, bison, Boost Spirit and a dozen others)

Comment: I used the term "token" improperly. All I need to do is check for EOF without consuming anything from the stream. Let's say the stream contains "1 2" and I read as ints. I would like this method to work after just **two** reads (i.e. `int a, b; cin >> a >> b; bool b = IsEof();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's impossible. How is the `IsEof` function supposed to know that the next item you intend to read is an int?

Should the following also not trigger any asserts?

```
 while(!IsEof(in))
 {
    int x;
    double y;
    if( rand() % 2 == 0 )
    {
       assert(in >> x);
    } else {
       assert(in >> y);
    }
 }
```

That said, you can use the `exceptions` method to keep the "house-keeping' in one place.

Instead of

```
   if(IsEof(is)) Input(is)
```

try

```
   is.exceptions( ifstream::eofbit /* | ifstream::failbit etc. if you like */ )
   try {
     Input(is);
   } catch(const ifstream::failure& ) {
   }
```

It doesn't stop you from reading before it's "too late", but it does obviate the need to have if(is >> x) if(is >> y) etc. in all the functions.

Answer (score 8):

The [istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) class has an eof bit that can be checked by using the `is.eof()` member.

Edit: So you want to see if the next character is the EOF marker without removing it from the stream? `if (is.peek() == EOF)` is probably what you want then. See the documentation for [istream::peek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek)

Comment: This does not work the expected way, something should be read **first** in order for eof() to work. Consider the following code:   
  while (IsEof(is)) {
    int something;
    assert(is >> something);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Normally,

```
if (std::is)
{ 
}
```

is enough. There is also .good(), .bad(), .fail() for more exact information

Here is a reference link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons for which there is no isEof function: it is hard to specify in an usable way.  For instance, operator>> usually begin by skipping white spaces (depending on a flag) while some other input functions are able to read space.  How would you isEof() handle the situation? Begin by skipping spaces or not? Would it depend on the flag used by operator>> or not?  Would it restore the white spaces in the stream or not?

My advice is use the standard idiom and characterize input failure instead of trying to predict only one cause of them: you'd still need to characterize and handle the others.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the general case there is no way of knowing if the next read operation will reach eof.

If the stream is connected to a keyboard, the EOF condition is that I will type Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+D at the next prompt. How would IsEof(is) detect that?

Comment: @leden - No, they have the same interface. This is just a reason for why it works the way it does.